# What types of businesses have tree roots available?

Tags: woodworking

I'm looking for some tree roots to make some custom tap handles. I live in the middle of Portland, Oregon so I can't exactly go cut down a tree by myself.

- Do lumberyards sell them?
- Do tree-removal companies typically have them left-over (before mulching)?
- Will I have to ask around for homeowners who have recently removed trees themselves?
- Are tree-root-furniture-makers likely to give up their source?

Comment: See the [meta discussion](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/607/2196) for more details about our product recommendation policy.

Comment: I've edited the question to try and remove the "shop for me" connotation. I've searched all over the internet, I just want some humans (who may have sourced this type of material before) to give me any advice they have about it.

Comment: "Where do I find X?" is almost always a shopping question to me, but I posted this over in the chatroom to see if anyone disagrees. I'm happy to defer to the community's decision. I don't think lumberyards will sell them. You can try calling tree removal companies, but they usually grind the stumps and leave the roots. Homeowners likely won't like the look of their yard after the roots have been dug up. You may have better luck finding someone that sells driftwood.

Comment: I'd look for a place that makes tree root furniture and see if they can tell you where to find a supply, or for something as small as a tap handle, maybe they can even sell or give you some small scraps.

Comment: My backyard has some you are more than welcome to, by all means help yourself. Please.

Comment: Here's my 2 cents' worth: I believe this question kind of straddles the "shop-for-me" line. On one hand, it asks for a specific kind of aesthetic and species. On the other, it's a genuine question asking about what kinds of stores carry such stuff. If OP would edit out the specifics, I don't see a difference between this question and an answer that talks about a generic home improvement store.

Comment: Since you live in Portland, there are several woodwork vendors at [Saturday Market](http://www.portlandsaturdaymarket.com/psm_vendor_directory.html) that might be able to give you some leads.

Comment: I see at least 3 others disagree with me, so I'll reopen.

Comment: Since googling "Tree roots for woodworking" yields no useful results, I'm more inclined to leave it open.  It really is an edge case, and I  won't criticize the closure.

Comment: Suggestion: migrate this to the new Woodworking area of SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a google search that proved readily useful:

[http://www.google.com/#q="tree+roots"+"woodworking"+project](http://www.google.com/#q=%22tree+roots%22+%22woodworking%22+project)

NOTE the quote marks employed to force occurrences.

First hit is for this [Pinterest page of Far West Forest](http://www.pinterest.com/farwestforest/woodworking-projects/). *"Woodworking with Don Juvet of Juvets Artistic Woodwork. He is a local artist who works with wood purchased from us, FarWest."*

Note the [photo of the "Coffee Table Made From Inverted Apple Tree Roots"](http://www.pinterest.com/pin/414260865694955022/), the root being obtained, apparently, from [Far West Forest in Sheridan CA](http://farwestforest.com/)

Two results for the term 'root' are obtained from their "Search Our Inventory" function.

Answer (score 2):

Roots from 'dead and down' trees can be found along river banks. Trees are blown down in storms or fall into the river due to erosion or disease.

Land that is being newly cleared for construction usually has a bulldozer pile of root debris in one corner or another.

Pet stores sell dead roots for terrariums.

Flower shops and nurseries use them for flower arrangements.